# Drawing equidistant points from the sides of a polygon

Tags: r, polygon, spatial

I am drawing a polygon with the following vertices

```
      x            y
-0.02208709 -0.039161304
 0.01184081 -0.020268029
 0.04578401 -0.001351904
 0.02210236  0.039176396
-0.01185226  0.020252146
-0.04578784  0.001352696
```

using the following code

```
plot(x,y)
polygon(x,y)
points(mean(x),mean(y),col="red")
```

[image]

Now I want to plot 50 equally-spaced points along the sides of polygon. Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: 50 random points with equal distance from the polygon, or 50 equally-spaced points along the polyline?

Comment: Here are 50 points that all have 0 distance from the edge of your polygon: `new_x <- runif(50, -0.02, 0.01); points(new_x, -0.0268618 + 0.5568654*new_x, pch=20)`.

Comment: @jbaums. Thanks for pointing out this point.  I want 50 equally-spaced points along the polyline. Clarified this in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `spsample` from the `sp` package.

First we'll load the library and read in your vertices.

```
library(sp)

xy <- read.table(text='x            y
-0.02208709 -0.039161304
0.01184081 -0.020268029
0.04578401 -0.001351904
0.02210236  0.039176396
-0.01185226  0.020252146
-0.04578784  0.001352696', header=TRUE)
```

Now create a `SpatialLines` object from the vertices. This is a bit messy - see `?SpatialLines` and `` ?`SpatialLines-Class` `` if you get stuck.

```
l <- SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(rbind(xy, xy[1, ])), ID=1)))
```

Then sample the points and coerce to a `data.frame` with `as.data.frame(pts)` or `coordinates(pts)`.

```
pts <- spsample(l, 50, type="regular")
coordinates(pts) # only the head shown here
##                 x           y
## [1,] -0.019343310 -0.03763339
## [2,] -0.014987452 -0.03520776
## [3,] -0.010631594 -0.03278213
## [4,] -0.006275735 -0.03035651
## [5,] -0.001919877 -0.02793088
## [6,]  0.002435981 -0.02550525

plot(l)
points(pts, pch=20)
```

[image]